# pom.xml in every directory or skip intermediate?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Say my project structure is as follows:

```
project
|-- servlet
`-- filters
    |-- filter1
    `-- filter2
```

Should I have a `filters/pom.xml` which aggregates `filter1` and `filter2`? Or should I directly include `filters/filter1` and `filters/filter2` in the top level `pom.xml`? This is of course assuming that the filters don't have common dependency etc that can benefit from a common parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two modules don't have anything in common that you'd like both of them to inherit, it makes sense to declare them directly in the main `pom.xml`:

```
<modules>
  ...
  <module>filters/filter1</module>
  <module>filters/filter2</module>
  ...
</modules>
```

You don't want to make your structure over complicated without a reason.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to make sure it is kosher to aggregate skip level modules. I will accept this answer soon as SO allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

IF there is nothing that filter1/filter2 can inherit from filters, and filters is not a maven module, then I would probably change the project structure to be closer to the convention I've seen.

```
project
|-- servlet
`-- filter1
`-- filter2
```

If that is not an option, then I would probably just include the modules directly as `filters/filter1` and `filters/filter2`

Comment: Thank you, it is not that I cannot pull them up to top level but that I don't want to.